# How to automatically select first source value in jquery, even not select value from the source

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

[image]

I need even the user does not select value from the autosuggesion, it automatically select first record. pls see my picture if user type Rice then it automatically select first, they press tab its fine, if they are directly click the curson on next form element, the rice city not selected. i can't able to pickup city id..

```
$(function() {
    $("#city_name_auto").autocomplete({
    selectFirst: true,
    delay: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(req, response) { 
        $.ajax({
        url: "auto_sug_all_cityname.php",
        dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
            response($.grep(data, function (item){return        matcher.test(item.value);}) );              
            }
        });
    },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .autocomplete({autoFocus: true}) to select first record

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your html mark up but you can simply insert a line of jquery after you did insert the livesearch result

```
//..doing livesearch
$('.option-result-class').first().attr('selected','selected');
```

or if you use a class to show the user what he selected go for

```
   $('.li-result-class').first().addClass('selectedVisualClass');
```

Comment: i am using text box not select box drop down

Comment: I  dont know what you mean by text box but if you have a customized "dropdown" menu go for the second option where you $('.li-result-class').first().addClass('selectedVisualClass'); .. and your first li will always be visual highlighted